# How do i make parsley.js plugin work with jeditable plugin

Tags: jquery, parsley.js, jeditable

I have tried inserting built in validator in the element

```
<td class="edit patient_fname" data-parsley-required id="{{$patient->PatientID}}">{{$patient->patient_fname}}</td>
```

The edit class is the one that makes table Jeditable/inlineeditor work.

Jeditable don't use form

after trying to submit it it just ignores parsley.js form validator 
Here is the link for  [Jeditable plugin](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) i am currently using

Should i find another validator plugin like parsley? like you validate inside javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable quite easily.
You'll need to add `td` to the list of `inputs`, and set the `value` option to a function that returns the value of the `td` to validate.